# A word that could mean apostate quisling

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking a for a word that describes someone who appears to have given up a particular belief and adopted an opposing one but in reality, only to subvert the newly adopted belief. This is a a particularly pernicious treachery, so I need something that gives that sense.
The closest I can get is an apostate quisling but that phrase fails to really describe it properly or indeed literally, as quisling would describe a traitor and not someone attempting to subvert from outside.
Does anyone know of a word that would fit my description.
Edit:
Or as Chris H points out perhaps a word that means a false apostate.
In response to Phil Sweet, in my scenario, they would be acting as part of a plot.

Comment: This isn't a good fit but its synonyms might be: *double agent*. In your case I'd invert the word order: they're a false apostate rather than an apostate traitor.

Comment: As you say, quislings (and fifth columnists) are almost *always* traitors. What you're talking about looks more like a [double agent](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/double-agent) (from the perspective of the enemy, who originally hired him as *their* spy, but actually he's secretly switched allegiance to *our* side).

Comment: 'religious agent provocateur'?

Comment: What is wrong with subversive?

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 Nothing per se but it doesn't describe the pernicious treachery, that I'm looking for.

Comment: Is this person acting completely alone, or are they part of a plot?

Comment: @PhilSweet Part of a plot

Answer (score 1):

An [infiltrator](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/infiltrator) is a person who joins an organisation in order to investigate, influence or damage the organisation they have joined.

In real life official infiltrators are often referred to as **undercover investigators** by law enforcement organisations or **moles** by the target organisation, but the situation is a popular subject for fiction.

Among many other works of fiction on this subject like **Harry's Game** and **A Perfect Spy** there is movie called [The Infiltrator](https://en.https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Infiltrator_(2016_film)m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Infiltrator_(2016_film)) about an FBI agent infiltrating a drug trafficking gang and an old G K Chesterton story called [The Man Who Was Thursday](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/184419.The_Man_Who_Was_Thursday) from 1908 where the central character infiltrates a gang of anarchists only to find, eventually, that the gang consists entirely of infiltrators.

Answer (score 0):

**turncoat**

> A person who deserts one party or cause in order to join an opposing
>   one.
>
> 'Redeem yourself or forever be consigned to history's judgment of
>   political turncoats, renegades and saboteurs.'
>   [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/turncoat)

Renegade and saboteur don't carry the connotation of switchings sides that turncoat does.

**double agent**

> An agent who pretends to act as a spy for one country or organization
>   while in fact acting on behalf of an enemy.
>   [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/double_agent)

Answer (score -1):

Defector, n.

person who relinquishes, absconds from, or flees duty in order to resume said duty on the opposing side of a conflict.

Comment: So, perhaps, you might modify the scenario to read as "a red herring defection," "a straw man defection," "a defection ruse," &c.

Comment: I rather like "a sham defection," personally.